# migrate the MMAPv1 generated data to WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, mmap, wiredtiger, database

I am running a (keystonejs) webapp using mongodb 3.0 as database. I cloned the webapp and run a second instance using a 3.2 mongodb release (on a generated but yet empty data base). What I need to do now is get the data from the first database to the second. Since mongodb 3.2 uses a different default storage engine which is WiredTiger the clone uses that one. However the original app uses MMAPv1. Is there a easy way to migrate data create by MMAPv1 to WiredTiger?

Comment: here a detailed description of the migration with replication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960659/how-to-migrate-from-mmapv1-to-wiredtiger-with-minimal-downtime-without-mongodump/41975065#41975065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a backup of the database on your old server using `mongodump`, restore it back to the new one using `mongorestore`, done. It's covered quite well in the documentation.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-standalone-wiredtiger/

Answer (score 3):

You can create replica set and add new machine to it. Doing so, you'll have latest data on newer server. Once replication is over, switch new machine to primary and shutdown old server if you want. This way you can easily clone your existing data to wiredTiger without loosing data or negatively effecting existing application.

Comment: That is definitely an option i will consider in the future. Thanks for sharing this Saleem

Comment: Initial sync puts tables in memory, so you need enough memory on your new machine matching size of a biggest table, or it fails.