# How to migrate from MMAPv1 to WiredTiger with minimal downtime without mongodump/mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, replication, wiredtiger, database

Most guidelines recommend to use mongodump/mongorestore, but for large product databases downtime can be very long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replication and an additional server for this or the same server if the load allows.

1. You need 3 running MongoDB instance:

   - Your server you want to update (remind that WiredTiger support since 3.0).
   - Second instance of MongoDB which can be run on an additional server. Database will be temporarily copied to it by the replication.
   - And the third instance of MongoDB is arbiter, which doesn’t store data and only participates in the election of primary server. The arbiter can be run on the additional server on a separate port.
2. Anyway you need to backup your database. You can run “*mongodump*” without parameters and directory “*./dump*” will be created with the database dump. You can use  “*--gzip*“ parameter to compress result size.

   ```
   mongodump --gzip
   ```

   Just in case, the command to restore:

   ```
   mongorestore --gzip
   ```

   It should be run in the same directory where “*./dump*” dir and “*--gzip*“ parameter should be added if used in “*mongodump*”.
3. Begin configure from the additional server. My target system is Linux RedHat without Internet, so I download and install MongoDB via RPM manually. Add the section to */etc/mongod.conf*:

   ```
   replication:
      oplogSizeMB: 10240
      replSetName: REPLICA
   ```

   Check that the net section look like this to allow access from other servers:

   ```
   net:
     bindIp: 0.0.0.0
     port: 27017
   ```

   and run:

   ```
   service mongod start
   ```
4. Run the third MongoDB instance - arbiter. It can work on the additional server on a different port. Create a temporary directory for the arbiter database:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/mongo
   chmod 777 -R /tmp/mongo
   ```

   and run:

   ```
   mongod --dbpath /tmp/mongo --port 27001 --replSet REPLICA \
       --fork --logpath /tmp/mongo/db1.log
   ```
5. Now configure the main server. Edit /etc/mongod.conf

   ```
   replication:
      oplogSizeMB: 10240
      replSetName: REPLICA
   ```

   and restart MongoDB on the main server:

   ```
   service mongod restart
   ```
6. It’s important! After restarting the main server read operations may be unavailable. I was getting the following error:

   ```
   { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "node is recovering", "code" : 13436 }
   ```

   So as quickly as possible you need to connect to MongoDB on the main server via “*mongo*” console and run the following command to configure replication:

   ```
   rs.initiate(
   {
     _id: "REPLICA",
     members: [
       { _id: 0, host : "<IP address of main server>:27017",
                 priority: 1.0 },
       { _id: 1, host : "<IP  address of additional server>:27017",
                 priority: 0.5 },
       { _id: 2, host : "<IP address of additional server(the arbiter)>:27001", 
                 arbiterOnly : true,  priority: 0.5  }
     ]
   }
   )
   ```

   After this operation all actions with MongoDB will be available and data synchronization will be started.

   I don’t recommend to use *rs.initiate()* on the main server without parameters as in most tutorials, because name of the main server will be configured by default as DNS-name from the */etc/hostname*. It's not very convenient for me because I use IP-addresses for communications in my projects.

   To check the synchronization progress you can call from “*mongo*” console:

   ```
   rs.status()
   ```

   Result example:

   ```
   {
      "set" : "REPLICA",
      "date" : ISODate("2017-01-19T14:30:34.292Z"),
      "myState" : 1,
      "term" : NumberLong(1),
      "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
      "members" : [
          {
              "_id" : 0,
              "name" : "<IP address of main server>:27017",
              "health" : 1.0,
              "state" : 1,
              "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
              "uptime" : 165,
              "optime" : {
                  "ts" : Timestamp(6377323060650835, 3),
                  "t" : NumberLong(1)
              },
              "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-01-19T14:30:33.000Z"),
              "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
              "electionTime" : Timestamp(6377322974751490, 1),
              "electionDate" : ISODate("2017-01-19T14:30:13.000Z"),
              "configVersion" : 1,
              "self" : true
          },
          {
              "_id" : 1,
              "name" : "<IP address of additional server>:27017",
              "health" : 1.0,
              "state" : 5,
              "stateStr" : "STARTUP2",
              "uptime" : 30,
              "optime" : {
                  "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                  "t" : NumberLong(-1)
              },
              "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
              "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-01-19T14:30:33.892Z"),
              "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-01-19T14:30:34.168Z"),
              "pingMs" : NumberLong(3),
              "syncingTo" : "<IP address of main server>:27017",
              "configVersion" : 1
          },
          {
              "_id" : 2,
              "name" : "<IP address of additional server (the arbiter)>:27001",
              "health" : 1.0,
              "state" : 7,
              "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
              "uptime" : 30,
              "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-01-19T14:30:33.841Z"),
              "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-01-19T14:30:30.158Z"),
              "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
              "configVersion" : 1
          }
      ],
      "ok" : 1.0
   }
   ```

   After “*stateStr*” of the additional server will be replaced from ”*STARTUP2*” to ”*SECONDARY*”, our servers are synchronized.
7. While we wait for the end of the synchronization, it is necessary to modify client applications a little bit they can work with all servers in replica.

   - If you use the ConnectionString, you should replace it with something like:

     ```
     mongodb://<IP address of main server>:27017,<IP address of additional server>:27017,<IP address of additional server (the arbiter)>:27001/?replicaSet=REPLICA
     ```
   - If you use C++ mongo-cxx-driver legacy, as I am, you should to use *mongo::DBClientReplicaSet* instead *mongo::DBClientConnection* and list all three servers in connection parameters, including the arbiter.
   - There is a third option - you can simply change IP of MongoDB server in clients after switching *PRIMARY*-*SECONDARY*, but it's not very fair.
8. After the synchronization has ended and an additional server status has established as *SECONDARY*, we need to switch the *PRIMARY* and *SECONDARY* by executing the command in “*mongo*” console on the main server. This is important because command will not work on the additional server.

   ```
   cfg = rs.conf()
   cfg.members[0].priority = 0.5
   cfg.members[1].priority = 1
   cfg.members[2].priority = 0.5
   rs.reconfig(cfg)
   ```

   Then check server status by executing:

   ```
   rs.status()
   ```
9. Stop the MongoDB on the main server

   ```
   service mongod stop
   ```

   and simply delete the entire contents of a directory with database. It is safe, because we have a working copy on the additional server, and in the beginning we have made a backup. Be careful. MongoDB doesn’t create a database directory itself. If you've deleted it, you need not only to restore

   ```
   mkdir /var/lib/mongo
   ```

   and setup owner:

   ```
   chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo
   ```
10. Check storage engine wiredTiger is configured in */etc/mongod.conf*. From 3.2 it is used by default:

    ```
    storage:
         ...
        engine: wiredTiger
        ...
    ```

    And run MongoDB:

    ```
    service mongod start
    ```

    The main server will get the configuration from the secondary server automatically and data will be synced back to WiredTiger storage.
11. After the synchronization is finished switch the *PRIMARY* server back. This operation should be performed on an additional server because it is the *PRIMARY* now.

    ```
    cfg = rs.conf()
    cfg.members[0].priority = 1
    cfg.members[1].priority = 0.5
    cfg.members[2].priority = 0.5
    rs.reconfig(cfg)
    ```
12. Return the old version of database clients or change *ConnectionString* back.
13. Now turn off replication if necessary. Remove 2 replication servers from the main server:

    ```
    rs.remove("<IP address of additional server>:27017")
    rs.remove("<IP address of additional server (the arbiter)>:27001")
    ```

    Remove all “*replication*” section from */etc/mongod.conf* and restart MongoDB:

    ```
    service mongod restart
    ```

    After these we get the warning when connected via the “*mongo*” console:

    ```
    2017-01-19T12:26:51.948+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: mongod started without --replSet yet 1 documents are present in local.system.replset
    2017-01-19T12:26:51.948+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          Restart with --replSet unless you are doing maintenance and  no other clients are connected.
    2017-01-19T12:26:51.948+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          The TTL collection monitor will not start because of this.
    ```

    To get rid of it, you need to remove the database “*local*”. There is only one collection “*startup_log*” in this database in default state, so you can do this without fear via “*mongo*” console

    ```
    use local
    db.dropDatabase()
    ```

    and restart MongoDB:

    ```
    service mongod restart
    ```

    If you will remove the “*local*” database before “*replication*” section from */etc/mongod.conf*, it is immediately restored. So I could not do only one MongoDB restart.
14. On the additional server perform the same action:

    - remove “*replication*“ section from */etc/mongod.conf*
    - restart MongoDB
    - drop the “*local*“ database
    - again restart
15. The arbiter just stop and remove:

    ```
    pkill -f /tmp/mongo
    rm -r /tmp/mongo
    ```